# Linux folder permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a folder in /srv/backups.  I have a users group that has access to the backups folder with rwx access.

[image]

I have added myself to the users group

[image]

but when i try to cd into the backups folder i keep getting a permession denied.

[image]

Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Comment: Ur question is in wrong place. There is a ubuntu forum

Comment: Try `groupadd -g users <user_name>`. Also check the permissions on the `/srv` directory - `ls -ld /srv` to check that you can read and execute in that directory.

Comment: This belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/, as it is Linux/Ubuntu related, and not programming related.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Its funny today i logged in and went to the folder without doing anything and i was able to get in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that your groups don't get updated until you log out and back in.